# How to convert a vertically written string into a horizontal string in text file

Tags: python, pandas

i have this issue with this text file where the contents are written like this.

```
AOPL
PREE
PAAM
LNCO
EGHN
 E
```

This is the result i am aiming for

```
APPLE,ORANGE,PEACH,LEMON
```

I try to use pandas to read the text file, but it just return back like this.

```
df = pd.read_fwf("fruits.txt", header=None, names = ['A'])
```

```
      A
1   AOPL
    PREE
    PAAM
    LNCO
    EGHN
     E
```

Then i am stuck here, my idea here is to put each letter into specific row and column and then stitch them back up horizontally. Is there a better method to tackle this vertical issue?

Comment: Will the width always be the same number, like width=4 for all rows, or it can have different values for different rows?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach using builtin `zip` function.
You can then feed this result into pandas to construct the DataFrame if needed.

```
>>> path = "fruits.txt"
>>> 
>>> with open(path) as f:
...     result = [
...         "".join(parts).strip()
...         for parts in zip(*f.readlines())
...         # This loop can also be written as 
...         # for parts in zip(*f)
...         # Thanks to @mozway
...     ]
... 
>>> print(result)
['APPLE', 'ORANGE', 'PEACH', 'LEMON']
```

If you want to start at a specific column, You could `slice` the `zip` object with `start` value as the required column number.

```
>> from itertools import islice
>>>
>>> path = "fruits.txt"
>>> with open(path) as f:
...     result = [
...         "".join(parts).strip()
...         # Here I am using 1 as column number.
...         for parts in islice(zip(*f), 1, None)
...     ]
... 
>>> print(result)
['ORANGE', 'PEACH', 'LEMON']
```

Please note that this solution assumes that all lines are of same length.

Comment: Maybe add explanations?

Comment: Note that you don't need to use `*f.readlines()`. `*f` would be more efficient since it's an iterator ;)

Comment: Oh thanks for this solution, how do i command this code to start at specific columns?

Comment: This only works if the input file has lines of all equal length. e.g., in this example, the last line would have to be padded to " E  "

Comment: @CtrlZ That's correct. I added it as a note.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use pandas if your goal is to have a string/list, but if you want a Series you could go with:

```
s = (pd.read_fwf("fruits.txt", header=None, widths=[1]*4)
       .stack()
       .groupby(level=1).agg(''.join)
     )
```

Or with [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

```
s = (pd.read_fwf("fruits.txt", header=None, widths=[1]*4)
       .agg(lambda x: ''.join(x.dropna()))
     )

# or

s = (pd.read_fwf("fruits.txt", header=None, widths=[1]*4)
       .fillna('').agg(lambda x: ''.join(x).strip())
     )
```

*or `.read_csv("fruits.txt", header=None, sep='(?<=.)(?=.)')`.*

Output:

```
0     APPLE
1    ORANGE
2     PEACH
3     LEMON
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the aid of additional modules and also allowing for input lines of varying lengths, you could build a dictionary then output the accumulated values.

```
SOURCE = "foo.txt"
TARGET = "foo_out.txt"
data = {}

with open(SOURCE) as f:
    for line in f:
        for i, c in enumerate(line.rstrip()):
            data.setdefault(i, []).append(c)

with open(TARGET, "w") as f:
    print(*("".join(w).strip() for w in data.values()), sep=",", file=f)
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You should open 'fruits.txt' in read mode
2. Edit the content and save it to a variable say `content`
   (For instance, with readlines method, a list is created containing lines. Either the required element(line), or the entire content can be changed.
3. Close the file. (Close does the job of saving and closing)
4. Open 'fruits.txt' file in write mode.
5. write the file with already created variable i.e `content`. This will remove the old content and replace with the new content.
6. Close the file.(If you don't close the new content will not be saved. And the file fill be empty as the old content is deleted.

To avoid closing each time, another method called `with open` is available. By using `with open` method, you don't need to close the file.

```
with open("fruits.txt",'r') as fr:
    content = fr.readlines()
    for i, v in enumerate(content):
        content[i] = v.replace('\n', ' ')
with open('fruits.txt', 'w') as fr:
    fr.writelines(content)
```

Comment: "Edit the content"? Why? How? "with open" is not a function.

Comment: @CtrlZ, Added explanation for 'edit the content'